# List conversion issue in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list in DynamoDB which I am trying to load in my API which is in C#.

"actors": [
    "Daniel Bruhl",
    "Chris Hemsworth",
    "Olivia Wilde"
  ],

The entity which I have created in the API is using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.

public List actors { get; set; }

Now when I query DynamoDB to get the list I get an exception for invalid cast conversion -

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Linq2DynamoDb.DataContext.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBList' to type 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.PrimitiveList'.

Can you please let tell if I am missing something?

Comment: Please check whether the actors are created as DynamoDB data type "L" (List) or "SS" (String Set).

Comment: The actors are created with data type "L"

Comment: Did you manage to get to a solution for this?